# C# browser zoom

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I am building a C# application and using the  web browser from the visual studio toolkit.. is it possible to enable this browser to do pinch zoom etc when browsing large images/pdf's for use on a tablet?

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 13):

You can do this by setting `body` `zoom` atribute:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com");
        }
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.Body.Style = "zoom:300%;";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is an old thread but I found something that seems to work really well. The problem with using the Document.Body zoom method is that your page will not be centered in the browser panel. Here is what I am using, it just uses the CONTROL + to zoom in.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    SendKeys.Send("^{+}");
}
```

For each SendKeys.Send("^{+}"); it will zoom the page 25% (125%, 150%, etc...)

Just remember to set the DocumentCompleted action to webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

in ie, if position fixed used, css zoom not work.
u must use browser zoom in that case.

```
SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();



    IE.DownloadComplete += new DWebBrowserEvents2_DownloadCompleteEventHandler(IE_DownloadComplete);

    object URL = "wcms.hankookilbo.com";

    IE.Visible = true;

    IE.Navigate2(ref URL);

    this.Visible = false;
}

private void IE_DownloadComplete()
{
    IE.ExecWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, 200, 0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The web browser control, as far as I'm aware, is an embedded instance of Internet Explorer.

I would imagine that if IE (or the adobe plugin) supports pinch and zoom on your tablet, that your app would automatically get that functionality as well.

Of course, I dont have access to your specific hardware and OS configuration, and that's about the best I can offer without more information.